# Automatically create database in python application

Tags: python, mysql, database, mariadb

I am relatively new to application development, but I'm working on a personal project and I would like it to automatically deploy a mariadb/mysql db on first install/through an option in the application. Now, I understand how to create a db, after the mariadb server has been set up, and I've got that part implemented and working. But what I would like to do is not have to install mariadb, configure the server, etc, and have the application handle that automatically. I feel like it must be possible, but I haven't been able to find an answer on how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have your application automatically install MariaDB & configure it on the machine you're running it on. And even if it could, then you wouldn't want to do that.

If you were to automatically install and configure the DB, then whenever you run your program for the first time on a new machine, it could take a really long time to install the DB. If you do want to automatically install & configure, then you're better off writing (or finding online) a bash script to do it. Then, you can just run the script separately and don't have to worry about any unexpected side effects.

Also, most of the time in production your DB isn't even on the same machine as your web app, especially if you're running it on Docker or some other form of containerization. The point of this is to take the strain off of the web app and let another isolated machine handle all the DB stuff. You could also use a service to handle your DB for you, so you don't have to install or configure anything, just provide your web app the URL, username, and password of your DB. This is likely your best bet if you don't want to do any DB configuration. I won't spend any time here listing services that can do it for you, but you can find hundred by just doing a Google search for "MariaDB hosting".

Comment: For what its worth, this isn't a web application. Its a local application that uses the database to store information on files, similar to something like calibre for ebooks. Though, I see where you're coming from. I guess my goal is just to improve user experience and not require self set up for the most part.

Comment: @Anath3ma If it's just for local storage, then you may be able to get away with using SQLite. With SQLite, you don't have to install anything on the system, just call the Python module and it'll make a database file.

Comment: This is really the answer I was looking for I think. Thank you!